# SSRS report: nested tablix visibility

Tags: reporting-services, axapta, ssrs-2012, dynamics-ax-2012-r3

I have created the Tablix below (using list). The lines are grouped by "LineNum".

In the highlited textbox I have added another tablix for BOMItems. Dataset is same as for parent tablix. Depending on one checkbox ("PrintBomItems") I want to track this line's visibility.

If I set visibility check on nested tablix, the values are / aren't displayed as expected, but the case is that the line itself is still visible between "Search name" and "LineAmount".

So I want to set visibility to the parent tablix's line, where the nested tablix is located, But can't achieve it.

Could you suggest anything?

[image]

If question isn't clear enough please ask me to clarify more.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I can't reproduce your exact scenario so I'm not sure this will work, but could you hide the details row of the parent tablix?

What I mean is right clicking on the row indicator (for lack of a better name) like this:

[image]

But do that for the parent tablix' row, not for the bom tablix.